# Do puppet conditionals ensure order, or do I still need to add metaparameters

Tags: puppet

I have code similar to the following:

```
class someclass($ensure = installed)
{    
    if($ensure == installed)
    {
        $installValue = installed
        file { "someprogram.msi":
            ensure => file,
            source => 'somewhere',
            path   => 'C:/puppet-files/someprogram.msi',
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $installValue = absent
    }


    package{ "someprogram":
        ensure  => $installValue,
        source  => 'C:/puppet-files/someprogram.msi',
    }
}
```

Does the if statement containing the file resource ensure that the file resource will get applied before the package resource? Or do I need to explicitly state this in the metaparameters? Also, I am assuming that the $installValue will always be set before the package is installed, is that correct?

Thank you,

Derongan

Comment: The code works, but I am not sure if it will always run in the correct order. Masterless/Master(ful?) shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify the ordering explicitly, however the variable will be initialised correctly.

The ordering of resources in Puppet 3 is deterministic, but essentially random as it's based on hashes of the resource titles.  In Puppet 3.3, this behaviour can be changed to the manifest order ([release notes](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/release_notes.html#configurable-resource-ordering)), but I wouldn't recommend relying on this - certainly if you're sharing the module, there's no guarantee that others use the same setting.

Since the file resource may not exist (if ensure => absent), you can't specify the relationship on the package resource.  Instead, add `before => Package['someprogram'],` to the file resource.

Comment: Thank you! So the order of the variables being set is always going to be fine but the resource ordering may change if I understand you correctly?

Comment: That's right - because variables are evaluated at compilation time, and resources are sent to agents.